# Invalid Operation Exception was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, model-view-controller

Hello guys can someone pls give me help here I'm newbie and I don't know what to do! the error is point to the SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader() it says ,

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

My codes is in below. Thanks in advance.

EmpListModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;

namespace AIStestv01.Models
{
    public class EmpListModel
    {
        public string BioID { get; set; }
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public string Dthired { get; set; }
        public string DeptID { get; set; }
        public string Active { get; set; }
        public string NTLogin { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EmpController

```
using AIStestv01.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AIStestv01.Controllers.AdminControllers
{
public class EmpController : Controller
{
    // GET: Emp
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WOPcon"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conObj = new SqlConnection(con))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("wsp_Test01", conObj);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            var model = new List<EmpListModel>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); //it says this is the error
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    var emp = new EmpListModel();
                    emp.BioID = Convert.ToString(rdr["BioID"]);
                    emp.Fullname = Convert.ToString(rdr["Fullname"]);
                    emp.Dthired = Convert.ToString(rdr["Dthired"]);
                    emp.DeptID = Convert.ToString(rdr["DeptID"]);
                    emp.Active = Convert.ToString(rdr["Active"]);
                    emp.NTLogin = Convert.ToString(rdr["NTLogin"]);

                    model.Add(emp);
                }
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

}

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<AIStestv01.Models.EmpListModel>  

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Bio ID</th>
        <th>FUllname</th>
        <th>Date Hired</th>
        <th>Dept ID</th>
        <th>Active</th>
        <th>NT LOgin</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var emp in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => emp.BioID)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => emp.Fullname)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => emp.Dthired)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => emp.DeptID)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => emp.Active)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => emp.NTLogin)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Something goes wrong with your stored procedure apparently. Have you debugged it on its own?

Comment: Please include the full exception details (including stack trace). Please include the source code for `wsp_Test01`.

Comment: wait ill edit my post

Comment: As has been said, there is an issue with your stored proc. Without that code, it is impossible to help. The error also advises that you are not catching the error, if you catch the error you will be able to see the exception which will give some more details.

Comment: it's been edited now

Comment: @J.Mar we just need to see the code for wsp_Test01, you haven't added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two using statements with the SqlConnection creation. In your SqlCommand, cmd, you are using the first connection - conObj, but you open with the conn.Open() the second connection. 
Leave out the second SqlConnection using, and open the first one.
Also it is ok to put in the using the SqlDataReader creation.

Edit: As suggested by NightOwl888 to point out the issue with the connection not opened, this is the changed code.
Edit 2: I've changed the return statement to include model list into the returning view.

```
using AIStestv01.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AIStestv01.Controllers.AdminControllers
{
    public class EmpController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Emp
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WOPcon"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conObj = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("wsp_Test01", conObj);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                var model = new List<EmpListModel>();

                conObj.Open();//Openning of the connection associated with the sql command

                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())//Using around the SqlDataReader to dispose it after use
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        var emp = new EmpListModel();
                        emp.BioID = Convert.ToString(rdr["BioID"]);
                        emp.Fullname = Convert.ToString(rdr["Fullname"]);
                        emp.Dthired = Convert.ToString(rdr["Dthired"]);
                        emp.DeptID = Convert.ToString(rdr["DeptID"]);
                        emp.Active = Convert.ToString(rdr["Active"]);
                        emp.NTLogin = Convert.ToString(rdr["NTLogin"]);

                        model.Add(emp);
                    }
                }
            }

            //do something with the 

            return View(model);//added model to use it in cshtml
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But why would that cause the exception? It is normally possible to have two connections to a database.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot execute the command without the openning the connection associated with that command first. And because of that you get the exception.

Comment: I see when Visual Studio shows the error it says this directly under the error "Additional information: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed."

I guess the original poster J. Mar missed that.

Comment: @Thomas - I concur with your assessment. But it would be better if you would post the corrected code in addition to a description of the correction for clarity.

Comment: @Thomas thanks for your code it works in my controller but now i get the new error its all about my model it says The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'AIStestv01.Models.EmpListModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[AIStestv01.Models.EmpListModel]'.

Comment: @J. Mar I've added to the return statement( "return View();") your list model, that you are trying to use in the View. I hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need two connections to perform this operation. A single connection will do the trick. Second, it seems the problem is related to the Data Type of the fields returned by your query. Try using a '?.ToString()' instead of that Convert.ToString. Also, consider handling the data type that comes from the database. For instance, DateTime columns can be converted to DateTime in C#, then you can use ToString('format') to extract the value.

Another suggestion is to remove all columns from your Data Reader loop, and start adding one by one, so you can isolate the one that is causing the issue.